# Como plotar modelos distintos de regressão utilizando os pacotes ggplot2 + ggpmisc ou gridExtra?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

Olá!

Estou com certa dificuldade ao gerar gráficos com modelos distintos de regressão (quadrático, linear) **(FIGURA 1)**, observa-se que os gráficos ficam soltos (escalas "free") ao usar o `grid.arrange()`, havendo a necessidade previamente de gerar 2 gráficos, com seus respectivos modelo de regressão, demandando tempo.

[image: FIGURA 1 - USANDO grid.arrange]
**FIGURA 1 - USANDO grid.arrange**

Normalmente utilizando o `ggplot2::ggplot()`, eu faço uso função do pacote `ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq()`, pois, ela já organiza as informações, e plota, sem a necessidade de ficar definindo as coordenadas (x,y).
porém eu não consigo listar dois modelos de regressão, no comando `stat_poly_eq(formula=)`. Fazendo com que uma grade de gráficos `facet_grid()` **(Fator1 x Fator2 x ... FatorN)**, apresente o mesmo modelo de ajuste para todas as combinações (FIGURA 2).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**FIGURA 2 - Utilizando ggplot()+facet_grid()**

Dúvidas:

**1. Como usar aplicar uma escala fixa, para o eixo x, ou y, pelo `grid.arrange`?** 
 (neste caso seria para retirar o excesso de informação, como legendas de eixo, e números no eixo.)

**2. Como usar dois modelos de ajuste de regressão no `ggplot2` utilizando o `ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq()`?**
(neste caso seria apenas para usar um `ggplot()`, evitando ter que gerar 2 gráficos e combiná-los com o `grid.arrange`).

**3. Como editar manualmente a equação a ser plotada pelo `ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq()`?**
(neste caso eu poderia gerar usando `expression()` os modelos distintos, e adicionar a significância de seus betas).

Base de dados, utilizada:

```
    require(ggplot2)
    require(ggpmisc)
    require(gridExtra)

base1<-structure(list(FAT1=c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L),VAR.Y=c(-0.8,-0.75,-0.473,-1.103,
-0.72,-0.667,-0.453,-0.58,-1.327,-0.94,-0.507,-0.68,-0.66,
-0.517,-0.61,-0.893,-1.007,-0.847,-0.767,-0.753,-0.5,
-0.9,-1.24,-1.5,-0.387,-0.4,-0.673,-0.587,-0.79,-0.6,
-0.453,-0.353,-0.413,-0.84,-1.5,-0.763,-0.453,-0.753,
-0.607,-1.1,-0.647,-0.88,-0.513,-0.717,-0.52,-1.093,-1.36,
-0.507),VAR.X=c(0.6193,0.5696,0.5252,0.5643,0.542,0.5694,
0.6386,0.5671,0.5023,0.5626,0.5039,0.5501,0.5966,0.5771,
0.478,0.5855,0.5473,0.5605,0.6068,0.5402,0.4239,0.5775,
0.5254,0.541,0.6267,0.5054,0.5453,0.5699,0.4933,0.5424,
0.5557,0.6236,0.5589,0.5628,0.5364,0.5947,0.5329,0.5283,
0.5062,0.5492,0.4803,0.5593,0.64,0.5602,0.5339,0.5546,
0.5138,0.5451)),class="data.frame",row.names=c(1L,2L,
3L,4L,5L,6L,13L,14L,15L,16L,17L,18L,25L,26L,27L,
28L,29L,30L,37L,38L,39L,40L,41L,42L,49L,50L,51L,52L,
53L,54L,61L,62L,63L,64L,65L,66L,73L,74L,75L,76L,77L,
78L,85L,86L,87L,88L,89L,90L))


base2<-structure(list(FAT1=c(2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L),VAR.Y=c(-0.64,-0.8,-0.46,-0.493,
-0.453,-0.387,-0.493,-0.567,-0.347,-0.6,-0.367,-0.97,
-0.62,-0.587,-0.507,-0.66,-0.413,-0.453,-0.6,-0.62,-0.647,
-1.033,-0.507,-0.55,-0.353,-0.4,-0.32,-0.313,-0.347,-0.367,
-0.487,-0.253,-0.413,-0.553,-0.493,-0.44,-0.767,-0.833,
-0.367,-0.713,-0.36,-0.5,-0.44,-0.293,-0.38,-0.427,-0.473,
-0.773),VAR.X=c(0.8934,0.7384,0.282,0.3243,0.2642,0.3908,
0.7625,0.7539,0.4381,0.7273,0.7282,0.4234,0.8397,0.8045,
0.4524,0.7576,0.7217,0.4341,0.855,0.7121,0.3929,0.7137,
0.7924,0.4006,0.3606,0.5003,0.5113,0.428,0.3586,0.4232,
0.6986,0.5425,0.4975,0.5746,0.4854,0.6243,0.9717,0.6435,
0.8064,0.8789,0.4311,0.4133,0.3477,0.2804,0.3823,0.3729,
0.2647,0.4872)),class="data.frame",row.names=c(7L,8L,
9L,10L,11L,12L,19L,20L,21L,22L,23L,24L,31L,32L,33L,
34L,35L,36L,43L,44L,45L,46L,47L,48L,55L,56L,57L,58L,
59L,60L,67L,68L,69L,70L,71L,72L,79L,80L,81L,82L,83L,
84L,91L,92L,93L,94L,95L,96L))

base3<-rbind(base1,base2)

graf1<-ggplot(base1, aes(y=VAR.Y,x=VAR.X))+facet_grid(.~FAT1)+
  geom_point(color="black")+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, span = .8,color="black")+
  theme_bw()+lims(y=c(-1.8,0))+
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y~I(x)+I(x^2),
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(Y))~`=`~", 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label..,  sep =  "*plain(\",\")~")), parse = TRUE)

graf2<-ggplot(base2, aes(y=VAR.Y,x=VAR.X))+facet_grid(.~FAT1)+
  geom_point(color="black")+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, span = .8,color="black")+
  theme_bw()+lims(y=c(-1.8,0))+
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y~I(x),
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(Y))~`=`~", 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label..,  sep =  "*plain(\",\")~")), parse = TRUE)

graf3<-grid.arrange(graf1,graf2,ncol=2)

ggplot(base3, aes(y=VAR.Y,x=VAR.X))+facet_grid(.~FAT1)+
  geom_point(color="black")+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, span = .8,color="black")+
  theme_bw()+lims(y=c(-1.8,0))+
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y~I(x)+I(x^2),
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(Y))~`=`~", 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label..,  sep =  "*plain(\",\")~")), parse = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há opção para que cada facet possua um tipo de regressão, tem que fazer dois gráficos separados. Para evitar repetição, pode escrever uma função.

Para unir os gráficos, usei o pacote *ggpubr*, que possui algumas comodidades em relação ao *gridExtra*. Como não tenho o pacote *ggpmisc* instalado, estou usando a função `ggpubr::stat_regline_equation` para plotar as equações.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

plot.reg <- function(df, var, formula) {
  form <- as.formula(paste("y ~", formula))
  ggplot(subset(df, FAT1 == var) , aes(VAR.X, VAR.Y)) +
    facet_grid(.~FAT1) +
    geom_point(color = "black") +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = form, se = FALSE, span = .8, color = "black") +
    #stat_poly_eq(formula = form,
    #             eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(Y))~`=`~",
    #             aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label..,  sep =  "*plain(\",\")~")), parse = TRUE) +
    stat_regline_equation(aes(label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "*plain(\",\")~~")),
                          formula = form) +
    lims(y = c(min(df[["VAR.Y"]]), max(df[["VAR.Y"]])+.2),
         x = c(min(df[["VAR.X"]]), max(df[["VAR.X"]]))) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
    theme_bw()
}

p1 <- plot.reg(base3, 1, "I(x)+I(x^2)")
p2 <- plot.reg(base3, 2, "I(x)")

annotate_figure(ggarrange(p1, p2+rremove("y.text")+rremove("y.ticks"),
                          nrow = 1, widths = c(1.1, 1)),
                left = names(base3)[2],
                bottom = names(base3)[3])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mesmo pode ser obtido com `gridExtra::grid.arrange`, é só uma questão de preferência pessoal.

Comment: Obrigado, são tantos pacotes, que as vezes esquecemos, digo pois, eu tinha esse pacote já instalado kkkk, vou me contentar em fazer manualmente :/ .

Comment: Pro que quer, `grid.arrange` vai funcionar igual.

Comment: `ggplot(base3[base3$FAT1==1,],aes(x=VAR.X,y=VAR.Y))+facet_grid(.~FAT1)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(formula=y~I(x)+I(x^2),method = "lm",se=FALSE,span=.8,color="black")+
  labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)+
geom_text(aes(label=expression(0.69^"ns"-5.058*x^"*"+4.482*x^{2*"*"}~~~italic(R)^{2}==0.107)))` Considerando a mesma base, você saberia me dizer como eu consigo contornar esse problema, ao tentar plotar uma expressão?

Comment: Experimente usar `ggpubr::stat_regline_equation()`

Comment: consegui usando uma função que criei para gerar equação com base no `lm()`, e dai tive de criar um `dt<-data.frame(x=x,y=y,eq=eq)` e o texto da expressão, `geom_text(data=dt,aes(label=eq),parse=T)` dessa forma eu conseguia colocar varias expressões, que o sistema "mapeava" e plotava.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que o que a pergunta pede é o seguinte.

Para ter dois fits, basta chamar `geom_smooth` duas vezes, uma para cada fórmula. E depois acrescentar as duas equações, ajustando as coordenadas da segunda equação de modo a não estar sobre a primeira. As cores das linhas ajustadas e das respetivas equações também são as mesmas.

E como se pode ver não é necessário utilizar o `grid.arrange`, `facet_grid` resolve o problema.

```
ggplot(base3, aes(x = VAR.X, y = VAR.Y)) + 
  geom_point(color = "black")+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", 
              formula = y ~ x,
              se = FALSE, 
              color = "black") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", 
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE),
              se = FALSE, 
              color = "blue") +
  lims(y = c(-1.8, 0)) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x,
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(Y))~`=`~", 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label..,  sep =  "*plain(\",\")~")), parse = TRUE) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE),
               label.y = 0.9, 
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(Y))~`=`~", 
               color = "blue",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label..,  sep =  "*plain(\",\")~")), parse = TRUE) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(. ~ FAT1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ainda não resolve meu problema, mas já é um caminho para quando eu quiser plotar vários modelos em um mesmo gráfico, eu consigo algo similar ao que você passou usando group dentro do `aes()` geral, dessa forma ele plota sem eu precisar add outra `stat_poly_eq()` e ou `geom_smooth()`. o que eu gostaria mesmo era, usando `face_grid()` por conta do layout de escalas combinadas, plotar duas equações diferentes, no caso a fig 1 com linear e a fig 2 com quadrática.